# How to extend a CSS family tree horizontally?

Tags: html, css

I have created a family tree using CSS.

[image]

The family tree works properly but the problem is that if there are too many lists in a row, it breaks the row at the right end of the line, and displays it on a new line.

How do I make this family tree extend horizontally without breaking the child elements? Even if I do not have a horizonal scroll at the bottom of the page, I just want to display this tree as is - without moving elements into a new line.

This is the code:

```css
.tree ul {
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  overflow-x: auto;
  float: left; text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #F39331;
  width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
  right: auto; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #F39331;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
  border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
  border-right: 1px solid #F39331;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #F39331;
  width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
  border: 1px solid #0F60AF;
  background-color: #0F60AF;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

bg_orange {
  border: 1px solid #F39331;
  background-color: #F39331;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #F39331; color: #fff; border: 1px solid #F39331;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Parent</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Child</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Great Grand Child</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Looking for help on how I can extend this horizontally?

Thanks.

Arjun

Comment: `overflow-y:scroll` should work

Comment: Thanks @Dark_thunder. I added this to '.tree ul' and '.tree li' CSS, but doesnt seem to work. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. Should I apply the 'overflow-y:scroll' somewhere else instead? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you could use css-flexbox by adding `display:flex` to `.tree ul` , this should work

```
display: flex;
padding-top: 20px;
position: relative;
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
```

also  you didn't seem to define a `width` to the parent `ul`, add  `width:100%` to `.tree ul` .

Comment: and for li remove scrolls  .tree li {
        /*overflow-x: auto;*/
        overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */

Answer (score 0):

full response with @Dark_thunder user

```
<style type="text/css">
.tree ul {
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding-top: 20px; position: relative;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;

    display: flex;
}

.tree li {
    /*overflow-x: auto;*/
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide scrollbars */ 
   
    float: left; text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;

    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```